# Hightcharts max 19 is rounded op to 20

Tags: javascript, highcharts, max, boundary

I created a line chart in Highcharts and i want the maximum to be 19. 
So i found the option max

```
yAxis: {
   max: 19;
}
```

But Highcharts rounds the max to 20 and i realy don't want this becouse 19 is the highest value posible for this variable. I've tested it with 21 and this results in a max of 30.

How can i for Highcharts to respect my max?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to the `endOnTick` setting. The default value is `true` which means that the y axis scale will end on a tick. If your data is between 0 and 19 there will be ticks at 0, 5, 10, 15 and 20.

Test with endOnTick set to `false`: http://jsfiddle.net/mVvGj/